# RadTreeView leave child enabled when parent is disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, telerik, radtreeview

I'm using a RadTreeView to display some data and I need to be able to enable/disable parents and children within the control independent of each other.  I'm finding, however, that disabling the parent always disables the children no matter what the children are set as, and I've not had any luck finding a way around this.  I have a sneaking suspicion that because the children are visual children of the parent within the layout, they will **always** enable/disable along with the parent no matter what I do.  Is this true?  If so, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my suspicion is correct - disabling the parent disables the children no matter what, so back to the drawing board.